# Vue emitting events from plugins

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I have a simple Vue plugin that has no components it just provides some methods to the user:

```js
export default {
    install(Vue, options) {
        // Unrelated stuff here.
    }

    Vue.prototype.$foo = () => {
        // Emit an event here.
    }
}
```

When the user calls the `foo` method I would like to emit an event for them to respond to but I'm not sure if there is a Vue way to do this or if I just have to use a `CustomEvent`.

Comment: Can't you simply [`$emit`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) one there? BTW, I think you've got a typo, you probably meant `Vue.prototype.$foo`.

Comment: @YomS.Yes you're right there was a typo, thank you for catching that. If I use `$emit` I don't know where I would use `v-on` to catch it since it's not a component.

Comment: Well, it actually *is* a component. So once `install`ed, you should be able to use `v-on` on the corresponding template, which depends on where or what component/element you want to attach this listener to.

Answer (score 1):

Just normally...

```
export default {
    install(Vue, options) {
        this.$on('event-name', () = {});
    }

    Vue.prototype.$foo = () => {
        this.$emit('event-name');
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this but the user has to respond to it, the plugin just emits the event.

Comment: The `Vue` object will be undefined when adding `$foo` to it's prototype, as it is out of the install function's scope.